# Почему иконка применяется к консоли, а не к приложению?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

Нашел еще решение альтернативное [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551605/how-to-set-applications-taskbar-icon-in-windows-7/1552105#1552105). Но при запуске из Pycharm, иконка отображается, но после pyinstaller, после процесса сборки exe формата, и при запуске этого исполняемого файла иконка теряется.

Билдил свое десктопное приложение с pyinstaller, но обнаружил что иконка не применяется для окна и проводника.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если билдить приложение с консолью, то видно что иконка отображается на консоли и в проводнике.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто может подсказать как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Пробовали `pyinstaller YOUR_APP.py --onefile --noconsol --icon=PATH_TO_ICON`?

Comment: @Никита я пробовал много разных комбинаций, и да, я без консоли собирал билд, я собрал с консолью, просто проверить, и вот так убедился что иконка встает в консоль, а не в приложение